# How can an iframe get its parent background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, transparency

I have a Pardot (Salesforce) form displayed in an `iframe` and control over the markup and scripts on both domains.  The form has a transparent background and sometimes the parent page's background photo or color does not have enough contrast with the text color of form labels.  You can't read *First Name* when it's dark text on a dark background.

My goal is to set a `body` class inside the `iframe` that is `.light-bg` or `.dark-bg` based on a color sampling of the parent element containing the frame.

In this code the `iframe` would be able to determine if `div.framed-lead-form` has a light or dark background.  There are JS plugins to get an element's color saturation (this one has an interesting license https://gist.github.com/larryfox/1636338) but I can't find anything that works through iframes.

```
<div class="framed-lead-form">
    <iframe src="//go.pardot.com/id" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: can use postMessage API to communicate between the 2 windows, or set `document.domain` inside iframe to match outer window and can access iframe with script that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made a fiddle with main document and iframe.
From main document sends theme with window post message
From iframe listens to message and sets background theme color

Main document:
https://jsfiddle.net/kristapsv/L1fd64b3/33/

```
(function($){

$.fn.lightOrDark = function(){
var r,b,g,hsp
  , a = this.css('background-color');

if (a.match(/^rgb/)) {
  a = a.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)$/);
  r = a[1];
  b = a[2];
  g = a[3];
} else {
  a = +("0x" + a.slice(1).replace( // thanks to jed : http://gist.github.com/983661
      a.length < 5 && /./g, '$&$&'
    )
  );
  r = a >> 16;
  b = a >> 8 & 255;
  g = a & 255;
}
hsp = Math.sqrt( // HSP equation from http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html
  0.299 * (r * r) +
  0.587 * (g * g) +
  0.114 * (b * b)
);
if (hsp>127.5) {
  return 'light';
} else {
  return 'dark';
}
}

})(jQuery);

var iframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe');

// Set here light/dark depending on container or whatever color
var theme =  $('.container').lightOrDark();

var jsonMessage = {
  'action' : 'set-theme',
  'theme' : theme
};

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(jsonMessage), '*');
```

Iframe:
https://jsfiddle.net/kristapsv/zLL9db1c/11/

```
var messageHandler = function (event) {
  var message;

  try {
    message = JSON.parse(event.data);
  } catch (e) {
    return;
  }

  switch (message.action) {
    case 'set-theme':
        setTheme(message.theme);
        break;
  }
};

var setTheme = function(theme) {
  $('.text-container')
    .removeClass('dark')
    .removeClass('light')
    .addClass(theme);
}

window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);
```

Comment: Updated with working color theme check using https://gist.github.com/larryfox/1636338

Comment: Cleve use of the framed fiddle!  That is a strong demo.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest as pointed by @charlietfl to look into the postMessage API in order to pass a certain message to the iframed html and then do something in javascript to change the background.

http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the src of the iframe, you could just include it as a parameter.

```
<div class="framed-lead-form">
    <iframe src="//go.pardot.com/id?bg=FF0000"></iframe>
</div>
```

You might need to get this color dynamically via Javascript in the parent document, but the idea is the same. You could do this on DOM load. Jquery example:

```
$(function() {
    var bgColor = getPageBgColor();
    $('#my-frame').attr('src', '//go.pardot.com/id?bg=' + bgColor);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a much simpler approach but I need something that doesn't require a person to know anything about hex colors or `GET` parameters.  Users will paste in the boilerplate form code anywhere so it has to be automatically aware of its background.

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like the postMessage solutions will be way too complicated for your users then. I would provide the users with HTML for an iframe AND a script tag then. The script would update the iframes params or perform a postMessage. It would still be one copy and past action, but more complicated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it should get you the background color from inside the iframe.

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('framed-lead-form').style.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: This would only help if the entire parent page uses the save background color. The goal here is to know what the iframe's containing parent element's color is.